# How do I prevent my sticky navbar from moving under my div elements?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this problem whereas I scroll down my page my sticky navbar tends do go under some div elements like(cards or pictures). I've had this problem for a while now and nothing I do seems to work. I've tried setting the z-index of the navbar to 9999, I've changed the position of the divs but nothing work. What do you think the cause is?

[image: image of problem]

[image: image of problem]

[image: image of problem]

CSS of navbar:

```
`.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.815);
    z-index: 9999;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;


}
`
```

Comment: Pls upload the source code.

Comment: What are the z-indexes of the images etc.? Also are you using any `transform: translate`'s on those?

And as a side note, when you find yourself using 9999 as a z-index is probably a bad idea. try to keep those as low as possible.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 already has a class called `.fixed-top` for the `.navbar` under [placement](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#placement) in the docs, but their z-index is only set to `1030` so you may have some z-indexing somewhere else on your content, or your markup may be in the wrong order or invalid.

Comment: i have't given any image a z-index

Comment: i tried increasing the z-index but it didn't work. only when i set the index to -1 it worked but my images were't showing

Comment: yes,i'm using transform for my image